# How can I step down 24V to 5.5V and 3.3V with separate grounds?

Tags: power-supply, power, circuit-design, grounding, ground-plane

I have a 24VDC 4A input that I need to step down to both 5VDC and 3.3VDC, but I need the 24V ground plane to be separate (isolated) from the 5V and 3.3V plane (these can have a shared ground).

What would be the best way to do it? Voltage divider? DC-DC converter? Something else?

Should I go from 24V to 5V to 3.3V or would it be better to do 24V to 5V and 24V to 3.3V? I'd need the 5V and 3V lines to be able to handle a maximum of 2A.

Comment: When you say you need a separate ground, do you mean that they need to be isolated?

Comment: 240V<->50V transformers are relatively easy to come across because of old PSTN and site-work ELV stuff. You can then bridge-rectify and stick some caps in. Distinctly steam-punk these days, but if you just want it for a personal project that should do fine, I think.

Comment: Switching buck supplies give you step-down and isolation, but it requires a transformer of adequate size to achieve the isolation. Not all DC-DC modules are isolated switchers, some could be using an inductor for the inductive element which will not provide isolation.

Comment: Of course a DC/DC converter is best, and most convenient. Many DC/DC converters have isolated outputs (and many don't, so you need to search for this feature specifically). Dual-output converters are a little bit rarer - it is possible to build one, or convert 5V down to 3.3V (double conversion is not as efficient of course).

Comment: Try googling "buck regulator with isolation" lots of possibilities. Also see https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva674c/snva674c.pdf or similar if you want to build your own.

Comment: Yes, the grounds should be isolated @Hearth